# Usb drive not showing in autorun lxterminal but is shown in gui windows?

Tags: raspbian, linux, lxterminal

First of all Thanks a lot for answering my question.
When Raspberry pi boots up normally, and in terminal I give the command 
->cd /media/pi 
->dir
I can see my Pendrive name Here and files inside. But when I have put lxterminal to launch on autostart
by :
-> cd /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
-> sudo nano autostart
-> @lxterminal

and I Navigate to media/pi the drive name doesnt show up? What am i missing. Actually I have  a python Program that copies files from local to pendrive Storage.

Comment: One reason is that you did not eject the USB stick properly. New versions of Raspbian will warn you that you should click the eject button before you remove the USB stick. But if you don't listen, everything still looks OK, but perhaps once in a millions times, you bad boy still remove the USB stick without first saying good bye, and she, is busy writing something, then memory contents might be corrupted, but still look OK, when not reading the corrupted section. The above is for new raspbians. Old raspbians are stupid and ill tempered, any thing bad or weird can happen will happen! :)

Comment: Worked it Out !, I had to mount the usb permanently. https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-mount-a-usb-flash-disk-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Ah, are you using a very old raspbian or a very special USB flash drive? I have been using buster and I never have to mount my 8G/16G USB flash drives, and also Samsung T5 500GB/1TB SSD drives (which looks like USB flash drives to buster)  and I never to do any mounting or unmounting.  I do remember I once used USB 500G/1T/2T HDD drives I did need to mount and unmount.  So I guess your "pen drives" are actually USB HDDs.

Comment: Please don't mark the title with [SOLVED]. It is not the way this site works. Instead make an answer and explain the solution. Then accept your own answer after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.